# Understanding Getter() and Setter() in Struts

Tags: java, struts2

How to invoke getter() and setter() methods in struts?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?... from where you want to invoke those getter and setters?

Comment: @Garis... i mean when will the methods get initialized .

Answer (score 8):

Your question is rather vague. But the typical scenario in Struts2 is: you have an action with  some properties which follow the Java bean conventions ( say, a 'myval' property is accesible via `getMyval()` and `setMyval()` public methods).

When invoking the action, the default configuration (with default interceptor stack) maps the http parameters calling the setter. Ej, if you call `http:/..../myAction.action?myval=xx` Struts2 will instance your action and call the method `setMyval("xx")` (if your property is not a string, struts2 will try to convert it).

After the action execution, when the results are displayed in the view (say,a JSP page), you might write  `<s:property value='myval' />` and Struts2 will invoke the method `getMyval()` of your action.

This is the most basic and typical workflow, but I'm simplyfing, everything is much more general and customizable.